# How to run Metro-style Remote Desktop in Windows 8 Pro?

Tags: windows-8

The only available *Remote Desktop Connection* application after installation of Windows 8 Pro is the desktop version, but [reviewers report](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6392/the-windows-rt-review/4) the availability of a Metro-styled version, at least on Windows RT. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not installed by default, but you can [download it from the Windows Store](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-us/app/remote-desktop/051f560e-5e9b-4dad-8b2e-fa5e0b05a480/m/ROW).

Comment: Just to note that self answers are both in the letter and the spirit of stack exchange rules. There was a slightly mean comment thread earlier, and well *self answering is fine*. I'm a little iffy on the original question though - it sort of lacks distinctiveness, and really it can't be that hard to search on the windows store. It also opens up the possibility of "how to run X metro app" - which eventually is going to end up with a lot of localised questions. I don't think the downvotes are warranted in any case.

Comment: Thank you @JourneymanGeek. I would like to add that "how to run X metro app" doesn't exactly apply here since in Windows RT the application _is_ installed by default, which might lead to confusion (and did in my case).